# Distribution of greatest number rolled with three dice

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

What is the distribution of X, if X is the greatest number rolled with three dice?

If $X=1$, then we need all three diceroll to be one, so $P(X=1) = (\frac16)^3.$

If $X = 2$, one of the dice must be a two, the other two can either be ones or twos, therefore $P(X=2) = \frac 16 * (\frac 26)^2$.

$P(X=3) = \frac 16 * (\frac 36)^2$.

So for $X=k$ where k in [1,6]: $P(X=k) = \frac 16 * (\frac k6)^2.$

Is this right?

Comment: Not quite. Note that your probabilities sum to about $.4213$ (and not $1$).  You are neglecting the fact that you can reorder the rolls.  Take $X=2$, for example.  The ways to do that are $\{2,1,1\},\{1,2,1\},\{1,1,2\},\{2,2,1\},\{2,1,2\},\{1,2,2\},\{2,2,2\}$. Hence there are $7$ ways to do it.  As there are $216$ possible rolls of three dice the probability is $\frac 7{216}$

Comment: Hint:  it is considerably easier to compute $P(X≤k)$.  Once you have all of those it is easy to deduce $P(X=k)$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $X_1,X_2,X_3$ be three independent random variables, uniformly distributed over $A=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, and $Z=\max(X_1,X_2,X_3)$. For any $n\in A$, the probability that $Z\leq n$ is the probability that *any* $X_i$ is $\leq n$, hence:
$$ \mathbb{P}[Z\leq n] = \left(\frac{n}{6}\right)^3 $$
and:
$$ \mathbb{P}[Z=n]=\mathbb{P}[Z\leq n]-\mathbb{P}[Z\leq(n-1)]=\color{red}{\frac{3n^2-3n+1}{216}}. $$
We may notice that:
$$ \mathbb{E}[Z]=\sum_{n=1}^{6}\frac{3n^3-3n^2+n}{216}=\frac{119}{24}=4.958\overline{3},$$
hence the best throw on three is almost five, in average.